# SQL server - How to avoid duplicate records using few fields in one view

Tags: sql-server

I have a source table on SQL Server which stores data everyday irrespective of any change in the attributes. For example

```
ACCT_ID           DATE   CNCY_C  BALN_A
200013818991    10/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    11/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    14/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    15/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    16/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    17/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    22/04/2014  AUD 0
200013818991    23/04/2014  AUD 0
200013818991    24/04/2014  AUD 0
200013818991    28/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    29/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    30/04/2014  AUD -500,000.00
200013818991    1/05/2014   AUD -500,000.00
```

Since the data is too huge, we only are interested to bring the records that have a change as below

```
ACCT_ID             DATE    CNCY_C  BALN_A
200013818991    10/04/2014  AUD   -500,000.00
200013818991    22/04/2014  AUD    0
200013818991    28/04/2014  AUD   -500,000.00
```

I don't have "create" access on the database to copy the data into another table and check using rank etc.. Is there any other way that I can achieve this using a view.. Appreciate your thoughts.

[Please refer to picture for better understanding of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPXwW.png)

Comment: Is it the presence of a row for the same ACCT_ID on two different dates showing a change? If so, are you interested in seeing those changes from yesterday, or any time before? DO you care if they have been inserted today i.e. there is no history ?

Comment: if you need a view you will also have to "CREATE" it!?

Answer (score 0):

You need a aggregation and a logic behind it.

This should help you

```
SELECT ACCT_ID,MIN(DATE),CNCY_C,BALN_A
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ACCT_ID,CNCY_C,BALN_A
```

You may need to decide what happens to the duplicate days. Do you want the first occurrence of a value, then just let the `MIN()` as it is. If you want the last occurrence you need to change it to `MAX()` instead.

Comment: The problem with MIN and MAX is.. For Ex., If balance on 1st,2nd and 3rd of jan is 100$ and on 4th Jan is 0.. and then again 5th and 6th Jan is 100$, then if we take a MIN(Date), we only get 1st Jan with 100$...  but we also need 5th..

Comment: I don't get it I think. You can use a window-function, but this may produce duplicate rows. But anyway, have you tried the script? It just provides the code you describe in your needed result. So whats the point?